# What mechanism to use for a monitor in Android

Tags: android, android-service

I have an application which accepts some data from the user and stores it in a DB.

I need to monitor this data (whether the application is running or not) and create notifications based on this. The data may change without user interaction, so I need this monitoring system to run even when the application is not running.

I have read up on AsyncTask, Services and Handlers, but I am confused as to what I should use for this. Can someone give me some direction?

My current idea is to use a background service, that is IntentService.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.

You need this to host the app outside of a user interface. The application by definition *must* be running to monitor the data, however the UI (and associated activities) do not. A `Service` is how you accomplish this.

Comment: I have a question though. Since Service runs in the UI thread, will it not get closed when the app closes? So should I use IntentService? And how do I get the IntentService to run indefinitely?

Comment: A `Service` does indeed run on the main thread. The UI thread happens to be the main thread, but that thread is not *only* for UI. It will not get closed just because the UI closes. This is in fact the entire reason for a `Service` (see above quote). That does mean that work in the primary thread of a `Service` can block the UI if your main app is running, so you do want to spawn a new thread either manually or with `IntentService`. I'd certainly advise looking at `IntentService`, but can't say if it's appropriate without understanding more about your app.